# my program don't enter a if statement in pygames

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

i got a problem, while developing my first python game (rock, paper, scissors with cards) with PyGames, i can't enter a certain amount of if statements.

```py
 whoWin(player_one, player_two) -> int:

    print ("player =", player_one.choosed_card, "ia =", player_two.choosed_card)
    if (player_one.choosed_card == player_two.choosed_card):
        print ("Equality among player.")
        return (0)
    elif (int(player_one.choosed_card) == 0 & int(player_two.choosed_card) == 2):
        print ("1")
        return (1)
    elif (int(player_one.choosed_card) == 1 & int(player_two.choosed_card) == 0):
        print ("2")
        return (1)
    elif (int(player_one.choosed_card) == 2 & int(player_two.choosed_card) == 1):
        print ("3")
        return (1)
    elif (int(player_one.choosed_card) == 2 & int(player_two.choosed_card) == 0):
        print ("4")
        return (2)
    elif (int(player_one.choosed_card) == 0 & int(player_two.choosed_card) == 1):
        print ("5")
        return (2)
    elif (int(player_one.choosed_card) == 1 & int(player_two.choosed_card) == 2):
        print ("6")
        return (2)
    print ("no return")
```

Im kinda stuck cause its the win condition, im printing the card choosed and everything work fine when player_one.card_choosed = 0, Otherwise the round end with no return or equality. I can show you the output if you want but i think its clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have fallen afoul of the difference between the [bitwise "and" operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations) `&` and the [logical "and" operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) `and`.

You definitely intended the second, but used the first, try modifying all of your conditions to use the logical "and" instead.

Comment: Thank you so much, too much of C habit in me ^^